# Google Chrome omnibox what is the class name?

Tags: google-chrome

What is new class name of omnibox field in version of chrome 29.0.1547.57 m?
The old class name was Chrome_OmniboxView

Comment: Related? https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=246644

Comment: Yes. But I don't understand how to work with new omnibox.Is there any solution?